# Can I simplify these three catch blocks?

Tags: java, exception

Can I somehow have this block of code in a method

```
        if (!printStackTrace_printed) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            printStackTrace_printed=true;
        }
        logStoreException(ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
```

and call it inside of each catch block and pass it the correct argument **ex** or **npe**

```
    catch (RationalTestException ex) {
        if (!printStackTrace_printed) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            printStackTrace_printed=true;
        }
        logStoreException(ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());

    } 
    catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        if (!printStackTrace_printed) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
            printStackTrace_printed=true;
        }
        logStoreException(npe);
        throw new Exception(npe.getMessage());

    }   
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (!printStackTrace_printed) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            printStackTrace_printed=true;
        }
        logStoreException(ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're catching `Exception` in the last catch, and all catch blocks are identical, you can remove entirely the other two catch blocks without affecting the program.

The reason it doesn't make any difference is that `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `Exception`, so catching `Exception` will also catch `NullPointerException` and any other Exceptions thrown in the try block.

Note that in general, catching `Exception` is considered to be an anti pattern, except at the top most level of a server call.

Comment: Isn't every catch block called in for different type of exception? RationalTestException catch block would be called in different situation than NullPointerException catch block. Can you ignore that all the catch blocks are the same?

Comment: So in my case `NullPointerException` catch block is not executed at all?

Comment: Could I really omit `RationalTestException` catch block and leave only  `Exception` in place?

Comment: @Radek -- When you have multiple `catch` clauses, they will be "scanned" in the order they're coded.  So any exception would first be checked to see if its a RationalTestException, then (if not that) NPE, then (the catch-all) Exception.  (The only exception class more general than Exception is Throwable.)  With the first two clauses removed, everything will fall into Exception, and, since the other two are subclasses of Exception they will get caught by that clause.

Comment: (But another option is to call a common method from the three separate catch clauses.  Again, since the other two are subclasses of Exception, the common method can have an Exception parameter.)

Comment: @HotLicks: what would be an Exception parameter in my case?

Comment: The common routine would receive a parameter that would be your "ex" or "npe" value.  The parameter could be typed as Exception since all three exception classes are assignment-compatible with Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can only enter one of those catch blocks, not all of them, so you don't need the 'printStackTrace_printed' boolean at all. It's also poor practice to catch one exception and throw another in general but if you have a reason to do it at all, you only need to catch Exception, not the other two. So your question mostly disappears.

Comment: I need the `printStackTrace_printed` boolean to make sure that I print the info only once. I have methods calling methods and the `main` one needs to know that there happened somewhere exception. How else can I do that without throwing another exception?